# Why do I have to re-include header files in C when running Ceedling?

Tags: c, gcc, ceedling, cmock

I have a C project which I intend to test with Ceedling, CMock, and Unity stack.
I do have an issue when running tests...

My project structure is below

```
mytest
    ├── lib
    │   ├── bar.c
    │   └── include
    │       └── bar.h
    ├── project.yml
    ├── src
    │   ├── foo.c
    │   └── include
    │       └── foo.h
    └── test
        ├── support
        └── test_foo.c
```

And my Ceedling project.yml file

```
---

# Notes:
# Sample project C code is not presently written to produce a release artifact.
# As such, release build options are disabled.
# This sample, therefore, only demonstrates running a collection of unit tests.

:project:
  :use_exceptions: FALSE
  :use_test_preprocessor: TRUE
  :use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
  :build_root: build
#  :release_build: TRUE
  :test_file_prefix: test_
  :which_ceedling: gem
  :ceedling_version: 0.31.1
  :default_tasks:
    - test:all

#:test_build:
#  :use_assembly: TRUE

#:release_build:
#  :output: MyApp.out
#  :use_assembly: FALSE

:environment:

:extension:
  :executable: .out

:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - src/**
    - src/include
    - lib/**
    - lib/include
  :support:
    - test/support
  :libraries: []

:defines:
  # in order to add common defines:
  #  1) remove the trailing [] from the :common: section
  #  2) add entries to the :common: section (e.g. :test: has TEST defined)
  :common: &common_defines []
  :test:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
  :test_preprocess:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST

:cmock:
  :mock_prefix: mock_
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :plugins:
    - :ignore
    - :callback
  :treat_as:
    uint8:    HEX8
    uint16:   HEX16
    uint32:   UINT32
    int8:     INT8
    bool:     UINT8

# Add -gcov to the plugins list to make sure of the gcov plugin
# You will need to have gcov and gcovr both installed to make it work.
# For more information on these options, see docs in plugins/gcov
:gcov:
  :reports:
    - HtmlDetailed
  :gcovr:
    :html_medium_threshold: 75
    :html_high_threshold: 90

#:tools:
# Ceedling defaults to using gcc for compiling, linking, etc.
# As [:tools] is blank, gcc will be used (so long as it's in your system path)
# See documentation to configure a given toolchain for use

# LIBRARIES
# These libraries are automatically injected into the build process. Those specified as
# common will be used in all types of builds. Otherwise, libraries can be injected in just
# tests or releases. These options are MERGED with the options in supplemental yaml files.
:libraries:
  :placement: :end
  :flag: "-l${1}"
  :path_flag: "-L ${1}"
  :system: []    # for example, you might list 'm' to grab the math library
  :test: []
  :release: []

:plugins:
  :load_paths:
    - "#{Ceedling.load_path}"
  :enabled:
    - stdout_pretty_tests_report
    - module_generator
...
```

bar.h:

```
int addMe(int a, int b);
```

bar.c:

```
#include "bar.h"

int addMe(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b;
}
```

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

    int addMore(int a, int b, int c);

#endif // FOO_H
```

foo.c:

```
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"

int addMore(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return addMe(a, b) + c;
}
```

My test file test_foo.c looks like this:

```
#include "unity.h"
#include "foo.h"

void setUp(void)
{
}

void tearDown(void)
{
}

void test_foo_addMore(void)
{
    printf("%d", addMore(1, 2, 3));
}
```

Running `ceedling test:all` I get an error that says this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: build/test/out/c/foo.o: in function `addMore':
/home/USER/mytest/src/foo.c:6: undefined reference to `addMe'
```

If Include the `bar.h` header file everything works, but why do I have to do this? I included `foo.h` where `bar.h` is already included.

I added the `src/include bin bin/include` file paths to the project.yml as well.

So, why is this?

Tried setting up the project the way I described and it did not act in the way I thought it would.

Comment: can we see addMore and addMe please, where are they defeined?

Comment: Look at you error string, particulary "/usr/bin/ld"  This is the linker/loader emitting this error.  By this point the include statements have been processes and their contents have been read.  My guess is that where every you defined `addMore` has not been passed to the linker (i.e you forgot either the *.o or the *.so file on the compile line).

Comment: @pm100 Hey, I've updated the question to include bar.h, bar.c, foo.h, and foo.c source code.

Comment: your problem is that the linker cannot find addMe, either you must compile it directly into the binary, or it must be in a lib referencedd by the project at link time. I dont know the build system you are using , plus I do not know wat you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

> If Include the bar.h header file everything works, but why do I have to do this?

Because that is how Ceedling works. From the [documentation](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/blob/master/docs/CeedlingPacket.md):

> Ceedling knows what files to compile and link into each individual test executable by way of the #include list contained in each test file. Any C source files in the configured search directories that correspond to the header files included in a test file will be compiled and linked into the resulting test fixture executable.

So, you need to explicitly include header file into test source file, so that Ceedling knows which source files to compile. If you include `bar.h`, then it will look for `bar.c`. Note that build will fail if your `.c` file is called something else, like `bar_new.c`.